# Text based webbrowser that supports JavaScript?

Tags: browser, javascript, lynx

If I

```
lynx beforeitsnews.com
```

then I can't see the page because it needs a JavaScript compatible webbrowser.

Are there any text-based webbrowsers that supports JavaScript?:

Comment: Isn't that basically any browser with just CSS/Images disabled? You want the DOM to be loaded as it is the only way you'll be able to have JS functioning properly.

Comment: @Niklas Not if you don't have a GUI running.

Comment: See also: [Command line browser with js support](http://superuser.com/q/448514/151741)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comments under [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8148) (which is old but provides some good pointers):

- [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) - experimental javascript support (as of 2005 - may be better now?)
- [links2](http://links.twibright.com/) - supports javascript and pipelining and image display without X
- [links-hacked](http://xray.sai.msu.ru/~karpov/links-hacked/) - ssl and some javascript support

Comment: elinks on Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't seem to have javascript support enabled

Comment: The article "[Building eLinks Text-based Web Browser with (Some Sort of) JavaScript Support](http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/02/09/building-elinks-text-based-web-browser-with-some-sort-of-javascript-support/)" describes how to get javascript configured in elinks, though it apparently still doesn't work with most pages.

Comment: links2 does *not* support javascript, although an old version once did (http://links.twibright.com/user_en.html)