# Command line browser with js support

Tags: linux, command-line, browser, javascript, web

Does anybody know good command line browser with js support?

Ideally I need following ability:

```
some-browser http://example.com > ~/page.html
```

It means that cli browser download html, execute js and output a page.

Comment: I haven't really played with it but maybe uzbl (http://uzbl.org/) could do it.

Comment: See also: [Text based webbrowser that supports JavaScript?](http://superuser.com/q/299190/151741)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm not aware of an *interactive* browser with js support but you should have a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which is defined as:

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit with JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.

To get the page's content after it's been rendered:

```
$ phantomjs save_page.js http://example.com > ~/page.html
```

with save_page.js:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function()
{
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

An interesting side-project is [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) which integrates PhantomJS with [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/), allowing the former to be used as a NodeJS module.

Comment: Spot on. Just what I was looking for. I didn't need to ask my question in the end

Comment: I just tried this on a page I created myself. It is dumping the page before the javascript runs. Any suggestions?

Comment: @abalter:  That obviously means there is a syntax error in your page.

Answer (score 7):

Edbrowse, an ed-style editor/browser optimized for blind users but appreciated by sysadmins for its scriptability, claims to support javascript based on Mozilla's engine.  It's at http://the-brannons.com/edbrowse/.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation for `elinks`](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manual.html), it supports JavaScript. See section 2.6.1 for information on installing SpiderMonkey.

Comment: It depends on how you compile the links (or elinks)

Answer (score 4):

If you are running linux, you can remote control Firefox using Ruby (and presumably other language bindings) with [watir-webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/), then after you have it working you can trick it into running without any display (but still hit the page, uploading downloading or scraping data) using [Xvfb](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml),

Answer (score 2):

In case a PNG of the webpage is enough and you don't need the HTML source, you should be able to use `webkit-image`, a small command line utility that comes with Ubuntu. It's however not exactly a feature rich application, so it doesn't offer much customization, it might however be a good starting point for further hacking and thus maybe even allow getting the processed HTML output relatively easily.